# From Django friendship model can we get the posts only from the users that a user follows

Tags: django

From Django friendship model can we get the posts only from the users that a user follows. Similiarly when a user block any other user will their post show?

Comment: Is this when using the library https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship? We need more details please.

Comment: yes the django-friendship library..well i'm thinking about working with it thats why i'm asking such question. please pardon me for this type of question. @TomHamiltonStubber